# Override Android GUI

Tags: android, android-layout

I am working on a special project of mine that should customize a bit the experience of Android users.
The idea is that we should have customized navigation buttons in every Activity that allow the user going back and forth in the application.

I understood one basically cannot hide the navigation buttons in Android (especially from 4.x onward); but one could override their behaviour.

My question is two-fold:

- Can one customize those buttons (changing their look&feel, size, ...)

If that cannot be done:

- Is it feasible to create a master class that extends Activity and that presents the buttons all the time (so that I could inherit this class whenever I need those buttons)?

All feedbacks and criticisms are welcome.
Also, if you have other ideas about how to solve this issue, or if you have done differently in one of your project, please point me in the right (*subjective*) direction.

BEST.

Comment: OK, from my experience I can say that you can create a master class to extend the buttons and you can override there style and behavior !. is that what you asking for  ?

Comment: Don't change anything that would make your UI alien to users. See the style guidelines http://developer.android.com/design/index.html

Comment: "Can one customize those buttons (changing their look&feel, size, ...)" -- Only by building your own ROM mod that contains the code for a revised system bar. BACK, HOME, etc. cannot be modified by an SDK application.

Comment: @Kuffs I know what are you talking about. But here we are talking of users with special needs that _unfortunately_ the UI guidelines cut out from the use of this amazing technologies. So this is a real need.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Of course you can customize existing `view`s, by many ways:

- You can change their styles, or background, states, etc.
- You can extend an existing view (`TextView` for example) and add properties

You can also define a custom `ViewGroup` by extending `ViewGroup` or a `Layout` (Linear, Relative, etc.).
Finally, you can create a view from scratch, extending `View`.

See the DOC [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/custom-components.html) about custom components

This lets you to do almost anything.

However, I would'nt recommand you to change the Android UI, because the user is familiar with it, and I think showing a "too customized" UI is not a good thing.

Hope this helps you

***Note**: If you want to customize the Android ActionBar, you will need to hide it and create your own (or use some libs like ActionBarSherlock)*

Comment: THanks @CFlex I think this is what I might need. So you are suggesting that rather then extending the capabilities of the Activity class I should extend the `ViewGroup` ... Is there any reason why this should be better than extending the Activity class?



About the customization comment, please refer to the reply to @Kuffs in the main post.

Comment: @2dvisio because if you want to customize the Android ActionBar you will need to define your own (ViewGroup or Layout) . I don't understand why Overriding some methods of your activity would let you to customize the design. AFAIK, the Android sdk don't let you to customize the standard ActionBar. Hope I was clear enough

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to hide the action bar

like

```
ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();
actionBar.hide();
```

and create a similar one (your own bar).

Comment: Hi @daigoor I am referring to the **navigation** bar. The activity bar is something else.